# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException mistake

Tags: java

I am trying to search through a file to print out scores. Here is what I have:

```
 while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String record = input.nextLine();
        String[] field = record.split(" ");
        if(field[1].equals(targetState)) { 
            System.out.print(field[0] + ": ");
            System.out.println(field[2]);
        }
    }
```

And the data in file looks like this:

```
2007,Alabama,252
```

When I ran this code, I get that `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.
I just wonder what is wrong with the code

Thanks

Comment: Or just read the exception. It tells you the index, the size of the collection, and the line where it occurred ...

Comment: Right -- read the very excellent exception.  It tells you exactly what's wrong and where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split using comma and not space. Change this

```
    String[] field = record.split(" ");
```

to

```
   String[] field = record.split(",");
```

As you don’t have the spaces in your input string, so it is not getting split and hence the output array does not have multiple items, leading to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`